# Eclipse crashes on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, 18.04, eclipse

I am running Ubuntu 18.04. I installed eclipse from Ubuntu Software but when I run eclipse I get the error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-05-20 19:19:03.099
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse doesn't start on ubuntu18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031171/eclipse-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu18-04?rq=1) has the answer: The repositories (universe) contain a very old version (3.8.1-11). However, in Ubuntu-Software you also find a Snap-package of a newer version (4.7.3a actually) which works fine.