# Eclipse won't open on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: eclipse, c++

Every time I try to open Eclipse in Ubuntu 18.04.2 I get an Unsatisfied Link Error and it will not open. I tried uninstalling but that did not help.

The error message:

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/NAME/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1549828758313.log
```

log file:

```
!SESSION Sun Feb 10 20:52:07 CET 2019 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-02-10 20:52:07.624
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

In terminal error message:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
Gtk-Message: 21:05:17.924: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

Comment: I've downloaded An IDE for C/C++ developers with Mylyn integration... From the website, not via terminal

Comment: It says: WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

default-jdk/bionic,now 2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02 amd64 [installed,automatic]
default-jdk-headless/bionic,now 2:1.10-63ubuntu1~02 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jdk/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 10.0.2+13-1ubuntu0.18.04.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jdk-headless/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 10.0.2+13-1ubuntu0.18.04.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openjdk-11-jre/bionic-updates,bionic-security,now 10.0.2+13-1ubuntu0.18.04.4 amd64 [installed,automatic]

Comment: Well apparently it did removed Eclipse...What should I do now? Repeat the installation? Btw I wanted Eclipse in the first place for C++

Comment: That did not work. Same error message. _Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"_

Comment: _OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0_

Comment: This might help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031171/eclipse-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: Somehow I managed to install this version https://snapcraft.io/eclipse without any errors or whatsoever. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** 
[This](https://snapcraft.io/eclipse) version works just fine without any errors. Had to uninstall previous version first. 
Bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1754886)