# Error message when running Eclipse in Terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, openjdk

Seems like the Java IDE Eclipse has issues running on my system.
When I try to start the program I receive the message:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0
```

This is the logfile:

```
!SESSION Wed Feb 13 20:52:53 CET 2019 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-02-13 20:52:53.576
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:566)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

How can I solve these errors?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the fast response. I tried that. But all that happened was that I was unable to start eclipse and had to reinstall it. Got this message after trying your solution: **bash: /usr/bin/eclipse: No such file or directory**.

Comment: Hey, I used the version from the software center. Apparently it was just outdated. Now I got the version from the official website and it seems to work. Thank you for your assistance. :)

Comment: Please don't put "solved" in the title. Instead, post an answer and mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it. (Yes, you can answer your own question.) Glad you figured it out btw :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse doesn't start on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031171/eclipse-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04) so actually, no need to post your answer

Comment: Thank you for the update on the conventions here.