# Eclipse on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-mate

I've just installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers on Ubuntu Mate. The console is giving me fatal errors:

```
(WebKitWebProcess:19041): GLib-CRITICAL **: 17:07:33.039: g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:19041): GLib-CRITICAL **: 17:07:33.039: g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed

(WebKitWebProcess:19041): GLib-CRITICAL **: 17:07:33.039: g_variant_get_int32: assertion 'g_variant_is_of_type (value, G_VARIANT_TYPE_INT32)' failed
**
ERROR:webkitgtk_extension.c:47:proxy_init: assertion failed: (parentUniqueId != 0)

(Eclipse:18968): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 17:08:34.496: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
```

Is there a trick to get eclipse running on Ubuntu-Mate?

Ubuntu-Mate 18.03.3 LTS (Bionic) 32-bit

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0), Build id: 20180917-1800

---

I've just installed Eclipse from the Ubuntu repository, because I thought the repository software will be compatible with the distro.

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

After launching eclipse from the console, an error occurs:

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/ron/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_3.8_155965261/configuration/1565714604868.log
```

This file says:

```
!SESSION Tue Aug 13 18:39:59 CEST 2019 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2019-08-13 18:39:59.324
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

My JDK settings:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/home/ron/jdk1.8.0_221

echo $PATH
/home/ron/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ron/jdk1.8.0_221/bin

echo $CLASSPATH 
/home/ron/jdk1.8.0_221/lib
```

Comment: It is known bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/eclipse/+bug/1784358 .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse doesn't start on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031171/eclipse-doesnt-start-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a work around. I Installed Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a), Build id: 20180405-1200 from www.eclipse.org. Starting it from a console eclispe is giving me the warning

```
(Eclipse:8036): Gtk-WARNING **: 21:10:39.771: Negative content width -1 (allocation 1, extents 1x1) while allocating gadget (node trough, owner GtkProgressBar)
```

I'm getting also the error:

```
(Eclipse:8036): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 21:12:28.572: gtk_box_gadget_distribute: assertion 'size >= 0' failed in GtkScrollbar
```

This is a known bug in eclipse since 2018.

[Eclispe Bug 530781](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=530781)

But other then that, everything seems to work sofar.